# Problems with output data on Serial Port

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, serial-port, c++-cli

I have a custom hardware and a code written in java that comunicates with it. It works perfectly. I'm rewritting the code in c++ for another application that uses only this language, and that's where the problems started. When I get the reading of the hardware, this should be the correct answer for the data received:

```
Manufacturer: NH/Resp - LPM
Product Name: ERGO AcqSyS v1.1
```

But on C++ I'm getting this:

```
Manufacturer: NH/Resp - LPM
Product Name:
```

Seems like the second read/write operation that would give me the Product Name is not working properly. But I can't figure out why. I'm using two separate arrays for the answer to make sure that one answer is not interfering in the other. Also tried to clean the buffer from the serial port after the first succesfull operation, but the error persists.
The weird thing is: if I add a third write/read operation, then the data that should have been the output from the second operation appear, but they appear on the third line where the response from the new operation should be, leaving the blank space after "Product Name:" and the result of the third operation isn't shown either. Something like this:

```
Manufacturer: NH/Resp - LPM
Product Name:                  //"ERGO AcqSyS v1.1" should be here and not on the line below.
Hardware Version: ERGO AcqSyS v1.1       //The answer for this is not shown.
```

This is the code in C++/CLI that I'm using:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#using <System.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO::Ports;
using namespace System::Threading;

public ref class Comunicacao 
{

private:
    static bool _continue;
    static SerialPort^ _serialPort;

public:
    static void Second()
    {

        auto CMD_NULL = gcnew array<System::Byte> {0x01}; //Tells the hardware that the communication is over. Must be executed after every write/read operation
        auto CMD_HELLOW_MANUFACTURER_NAME = gcnew array<System::Byte> {0x03}; //Requests the Manufacturer Name from the hardware
        auto CMD_HELLOW_PROD_NAME = gcnew array<System::Byte> {0x04}; //Requests the Product Name from the hardware
        array<Byte>^ bufferReceived;
        String^ identifierString; 
        array<Byte>^ bufferReceived2;
        String^ identifierString2; 

        // Create a new SerialPort object with default settings.
        _serialPort = gcnew SerialPort();

        // Allow the user to set the appropriate properties.
        _serialPort->PortName = "COM3";
        _serialPort->BaudRate = 9600;
        _serialPort->Parity = Parity::None;
        _serialPort->DataBits = 8;
        _serialPort->StopBits = StopBits::One;
        _serialPort->Handshake = Handshake::None;

        // Set the read/write timeouts
        _serialPort->ReadTimeout = 500;
        _serialPort->WriteTimeout = 500;

        _serialPort->Open();


//This gives the correct output

        _serialPort->Write(CMD_HELLOW_MANUFACTURER_NAME, 0, CMD_HELLOW_MANUFACTURER_NAME->Length);
        bufferReceived = gcnew array<Byte>(_serialPort->BytesToRead+1);
        _serialPort->Read(bufferReceived, 0, bufferReceived->Length);
        bufferReceived[bufferReceived->Length-1] = '\0';
        identifierString = System::Text::Encoding::ASCII->GetString(bufferReceived);
        Console::Write("Manufacturer: ");
        Console::Write(identifierString->Substring(2));
        _serialPort->Write(CMD_NULL, 0, CMD_NULL->Length);


//The code below doesn't output its result

        _serialPort->Write(CMD_HELLOW_PROD_NAME, 0, CMD_HELLOW_PROD_NAME->Length);
        bufferReceived2 = gcnew array<Byte>(_serialPort->BytesToRead + 1);
        _serialPort->Read(bufferReceived2, 0, bufferReceived2->Length);
        bufferReceived2[bufferReceived2->Length-1] = '\0';
        identifierString2 = System::Text::Encoding::ASCII->GetString(bufferReceived2);
        Console::Write("\nProduct Name: ");
        Console::Write(identifierString2->Substring(1));
        _serialPort->Write(CMD_NULL, 0, CMD_NULL->Length);

        _serialPort->Close();

    }

};


int main()
{
    Comunicacao::Second();
}
```

This code came from this documention: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 for this. Visual Studio is required by the new application to compile, that's why I'm using it and not other tools.
I use the substring function in the code 'cause the first two informations on the array are the code for the command executed and doesn't need to be shown to the user.
I'm new to C++ and more yet to C++/CLI, so I'm having a hard time finding what is wrong.

Does anyone know how can I obtain the correct output?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You must never ignore the return value of Read() or assume that BytesToRead is exactly as many bytes as you want.  You will only get what is available in the receive buffer.  It is not obvious what kind of protocol the device uses to tell you that you got the complete response.  A unique character would be typical, like a binary 0 or a linefeed.  Which helps you to use ReadTo().

Comment: I figured it out... the software is faster than the hardware, so my code is executing the requests faster than the hardware can provide. I need to find a good way to check if the array<byte>^ bufferReceived is still empty after the first read before proceeding to the next operation. If it's empty, than I order it to read again until it's not and then proceed to the next write/read operation.